# Postgres - casting text to ltree

Tags: postgresql, ltree

Im new to postgres and am looking to utilize ltree for a hierarchal data structure.

I have the both the data and the ltree structure (ie domain.class.sublass) in varchar columns, and need to cast the ltree structure into another column with the proper ltree data type.

Ive identified text2ltree as the best way to likely manage this but havent made much headway even after reading the ltree documentation  and ltree function information

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ltree.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-formatting.html

Ive tried many combinations of the below

```
 alter table codes
alter column joinedclassname type ltree using text2ltree(joinedclassname);
```

but receive the following error:

> ```
> ERROR:  syntax error at position 26
> ********** Error **********
>
> ERROR: syntax error at position 26
> SQL state: 42601
> ```

Ive also tried the following and recieved the same error:

> ```
> alter table codes
> alter column joinedclassname type ltree using joinedclassname::ltree;
> ```

How do I cast a ltree hiearchary from a varchar column to a column with a ltree data type?

Thanks!

Comment: [does this example help?](https://coderwall.com/p/whf3-a/hierarchical-data-in-postgres)

Comment: Are you aware of recursive queries? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html

Comment: your actions sequence is ok. error occures at word `column` - I suspect hidden symbols or smth. try this line: `alter table codes alter column joinedclassname type ltree using path::ltree;` as it - without adding extra spaces or such

Comment: Hi vao tsun, thanks for taking the time. I tried your suggestion, same outcome I updated my question to show this also.

Answer (score 7):

Figured it out:

ltree doesnt play well with hyphens and whitespace. Once I concatenated the value and  stripped out the hyphens and whitespace, it worked fine.

```
SELECT text2ltree(replace(concat_ws('.', Systemname::text, SubsystemName::text,ClassName::text,SubclassName::text),'-','_')) FROM codes;
```